# google-api-ruby-client: batchupdate spreadsheet values

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer, google-api-ruby-client

Following the instructions laid out [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) to perform a batch update.

First, I built out the required ValueRange object like so:

```
values = [
  ["first", "title", "second", "url", "long"]
]

range = "WorksheetInParentSpreadsheet!A1:M"

data = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new
data.values = values
data.major_dimension = 'ROWS'
data.range = range
```

Next used info in 1 above to built out the request like so:

```
spreadsheet = `spreadsheet_object`
request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateValuesRequest.new
request.data = data
request.value_input_option = value_input_option
```

Finally, I make the request:

```
sheet_service.batch_update_values(spreadsheet.id, request)
```

I expect this to update the sheet but instead I get this error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `each_with_index' for #<Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange:0x00007ffc7826c2e0>
```

It appears that ValueRange either:

- does not respond to `each_with_index`
- or the `ValueRange` object provided (data) is missing an enumerable object

Usually would inspect the gem I am using but in this case response doesn't provide line or a file to narrow the error down to.

I am stumped. What am I missing?

Complete Code:

```
values = [
  ["first", "title", "second", "url", "long"]
]

range = "WorksheetInParentSpreadsheet!A1:M"

data = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new
data.values = values
data.major_dimension = 'ROWS'

spreadsheet = `spreadsheet_object`
request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateValuesRequest.new
request.data = data
request.value_input_option = value_input_option
data.range = range

sheet_service.batch_update_values(spreadsheet.id, request)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please include your complete code if that would be possible?

Comment: Hi @RonM! Edited to make clear what  the complete code is. The only step missing is the authorization headers, which isn't the problem as the request to the client goes through thus signifying that authorization works.

Comment: Yes I was wondering to check your sheet_service cause pretty much all of your other objects are correct upon checking the api library. Just for us to replicate your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At the method of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate in Sheets API, the value of property of `data` is required to be an array.
- `value_input_option` is not declared.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
value_input_option = "USER_ENTERED" # Please set this for your actual situation.

values = [
  ["first", "title", "second", "url", "long"]
]

range = "WorksheetInParentSpreadsheet!A1:M"

data = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::ValueRange.new
data.values = values
data.major_dimension = 'ROWS'

spreadsheet = `spreadsheet_object`
request = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::BatchUpdateValuesRequest.new

request.data = [data] # <--- Modified

request.value_input_option = value_input_option
data.range = range

sheet_service.batch_update_values(spreadsheet.id, request)
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the values of `sheet_service` and `spreadsheet.id` are the valid values. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: I totally missed data needing to be an array; Thank you!

Comment: @SavageSuga Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.